# How would you determine whether an object is at equilibrium?

Tags: forces, definition, statics, equilibrium

How would you determine whether an object is at equilibrium or not?

What is the definition of [equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium)?

Comment: By comparing the object against the definition of equilibrium of course. Could you be more specific about what you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: This question (v3) seems closable since a straightforward Google search would immediately provide the answer, cf. e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9/2451) and [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/121/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 1):

Static equilibrium requires that the sum of all forces is 0,$$\sum F=0$$ and the sum of all torques is 0, $$\sum \tau =0$$ Be aware that force and torque is a vector; they have both magnitude and direction.

You will usually want to separate a force into its components such that all forces are either parallel or perpendicular to each other. Then apply the equation above for force separately for x- and y- axes.

The direction of torque follows the right-hand rule. If unsure, just think of counter-clockwise as positive and clockwise as negative. Then apply the equation for torque.

Answer (score 0):

There a several notions of equilibrium. These are discussed in an informative online encyclopedia called "[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org)", which I recommend. The link to the mechanical equilibrium section is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium). (I assume you mean mechanical equilbrium since there is the forces tag.) If you read the article and have trouble understanding anything, please ask a more specific question about what you are having trouble understanding.